# ElasticSearch filter results by role

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, filter, authorization

I have a requirement where I need to filter the results of an ElasticSearch query according with the user role and the combination of permissions that are within the role.

However, performing the filtering after the results being retrieved from ES it will break the pagination. Building the pagination on the application layer may not work properly as is going to impact the results when we have facet search.

So, my idea was trying to include all the authorisation logic in the ES query, or build a custom plugin to deal with it, but I am bit reluctant which one is the best approach as I am not really an expert in ES neither I have written any plugin before.

It is possible to write a plugin to this work for us? It is considered a good approach?